# How to remove tikz node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

This codes places the english alphabet from a to y in a 5 by 5 square and then removes s in (3,3) from view by imposing a white square on it. Is there a way to properly delete a node instead of covering it with other objects?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,4}
\foreach \j in {0,...,4} 
\node at (\i,\j) {$\alphalph{5*\j+\i+1}$};
\fill[color=white] (2.5,2.5) rectangle (3.5,3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Minor suggestion: use `anchor=base` or `anchor=mid` to vertically align the letters nicely.

Answer (score 8):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{alphalph}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,4}
\foreach \j in {0,...,4}
{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{int(5*\j+\i+1)}
    \ifnum\x=19
        \else
    \node[anchor=mid]  at (\i,\j) {$\alphalph{\x}$};
    \fi;
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Considered is @Andrew Stacey comment regarding nodes style. Now the vertically align of letters is nicely.

Comment: +1 Although, rather than using `\pgfmathsetmacro`  I would write `\foreach \j [evaluate=\j as \x using {int(5*\j+\i+1)}] in {0,...,4}{...}`  :)

Comment: @3141592653589793238, matter of personal preference. I don't see any advantage to use your suggestion. With `\pgfmathsetmacro` the code is a wee bit shorter. I don't know, if there is difference in compilation time.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to hide a node is to convert it to a `coordinate` (which is just a text-less and border-less node).

This will still define a node and still applies all options that would be valid for a coordinate (the style `every coordinate` and things like `label`s or other `append after command`s).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[letter s/.style=coordinate]
\foreach \l[count=\i from 0] in {a,...,y}
  \node[anchor=base, letter \l/.try] at ({mod(\i,5)},{int(\i/5)}) {$\l$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

We can also use the `letter s` style to disable a style that would place a node so that not even a coordinate will be placed.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  place node/.style={insert path={
    node[anchor=base] at ({mod(\i,5)},{int(\i/5)}) {$\l$}}},
  letter s/.style={place node/.style=}]
\foreach \l[count=\i from 0] in {a,...,y}
  \path [letter \l/.try, place node];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

With one loop for this, you can just skip the `18` (`s`).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,17,19,20,...,24}
  \node[anchor=base] at ({mod(\i,5)},{int(\i/5)}) {$\alphalph{\i+1}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or again without `alphalph`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \l[count=\i from 0, evaluate={\I=\i+(\i>17?1:0);}] in {a,...,r,t,u,...,y}
  \node[anchor=base] at ({mod(\I,5)},{int(\I/5)}) {$\l$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

And with a simple `node if` key you can just not put a node on the path:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.misc}
\tikzset{node if/.style 2 args={/utils/if={#1}{insert path={node#2}}{}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \l[count=\i from 0] in {a,...,y}
  \path [node if={\i!=18}{[anchor=base] at ({mod(\i,5)},{int(\i/5)}) {$\l$}}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course, the `/utils/if` can also simply be used to apply `coordinate` to the node like in the first example.

Comment: Wow! Very comprehensive and instructive answer(s).